# can google detect structured data if using multiple sitemaps?

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search-console

I have tested my webpages using Google Structured Data Testing Tool. It’s been several months now and Google still has not detected structured data on my site.

I have 2 sitemaps `sitemap.xml` and `us-sitemap.xml`.

Google is detecting structured data from a link in `sitemap.xml` but it is not detecting structured data in any link submitted in `us-sitemap.xml`. Does the sitemap has to be called `sitemap.xml` for it to work properly or is there something else that I need to do?

This is the site in question: http://www.findazan.info

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sitemaps with different names, these should preferably be declared in your [robots.txt](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/robots-txt-implementation.html) file as following:

```
sitemap: http://yoursite.com/sitemap.xml
sitemap: http://yoursite.com/us-sitemap.xml
```

Alternatively, your could submit both to all search engines, but that is extra work...